# How to take samples using fpga?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, spartan

I want to take samples of digital data coming externaly to FPGA spartan 3.
I want to take 1000 samples/sec initially. How to select a clock frequency in vhdl coding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use a counter to generate a lower frequency clock signal.

Multiple clock frequencies in an FPGA cause a variety of design problems, some of which come under the heading of "advanced topics" and, while they can (if necessary) all be dealt with and solved, learning how to use a single fast clock is both simpler and generally better practice (synchronous design).

Instead, use whatever fast clock your FPGA board provides, and generate lower frequency timing signals from it, and - crucially - use them as clock enables, not clock signals.

DLLs, DCMs, PLLs and other clock managers do have their uses, but generating 1 kHz clock signals is generally not a good use, even if their limitations permit it. This application is just crying out for a clock enable...

Also, don't mess around with magic numbers, let the VHDL compiler do the work! I have put the timing requirements in a package, so you can share them with the testbench and anything else that needs to use them.

```
package timing is

    -- Change the first two constants to match your system requirements...
    constant Clock_Freq  : real := 40.0E6;
    constant Sample_Rate : real := 1000.0;

    -- These are calculated from the above, so stay correct when you make changes
    constant Divide      : natural := natural(Clock_Freq / Sample_Rate);
    -- sometimes you also need a period, e.g. in a testbench.
    constant clock_period : time := 1 sec / Clock_Freq;

end package timing;
```

And we can write the sampler as follows:
(I have split the clock enable out into a separate process to clarify the use of clock enables, but the two processes could be easily rolled into one for some further simplification; the "sample" signal would then be unnecessary)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.timing.all;

entity sampler is
    Port (
        Clock   : in  std_logic;
        Reset   : in  std_logic;
        ADC_In  : in  signed(7 downto 0);   
        -- signed for audio, or unsigned, depending on your app
        Sampled : out signed(7 downto 0);   
    );
end sampler;

architecture Behavioral of Sampler is
    signal Sample : std_logic;
begin

    Gen_Sample : process (Clock,Reset) 
    variable Count : natural;
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            Sample     <= '0';
            Count      := 0;
        elsif rising_edge(Clock) then
            Sample     <= '0';
            Count      := Count + 1;
            if Count = Divide then
                Sample <= '1';
                Count  := 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    Sample_Data : process (Clock) 
    begin
        if rising_edge(Clock) then
            if Sample = '1' then
                Sampled <= ADC_In;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2):

The base clock must be based on an external clock, and can't be generated just through internal resources in a Spartan-3 FPGA.  If required, you can use the Spartan-3 FPGA Digital Clock Manager (DCM) resources to scale the external clock.  Synthesized VHDL code in itself can't generate a clock.

Once you have some base clock at a higher frequency, for example 100 MHz, you can easily divide this down to generate an indication at 1 kHz for sampling of the external input.

Comment: I believe that the spartan 3 devices DCMs can't output something lower than a few MHz (if memory serves it's ~4MHz.).  That stated some simple enable logic ought to do the trick.

Comment: @FarhadA No.  Why?  http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug331.pdf  Minimum DCM input frequency on the spartan 3a-dsp is 5 MHz (see page 81 in the same PDF).  Minimum clkfx out is 5MHz (the ~4MHz I referenced).  The best the divide by can do on spartan 3a-dsp is 16. 5MHz/16 is 312 kHz (so less than a few MHz, but my point still stands) : Last time I checked 1000 Hz * 16 <<< 5 MHz.  Unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: Well @Doov you seems to have missed the section under: "Input Clock Frequency Range", under "DFS Unit Clock Input Frequency Requirements". If you look under that and search "Digital Frequency Synthesizer (DFS)" you will see that what you said is only valid for the DLL, but not when the "DFS_FREQUENCY_MODE" is used.

Comment: @FarhadA fair point, but I still see a minimum input frequency of 1 MHz for spartan 3a.  1 MHz/16 is still >>> 1 kHz.  Even if he's using spartan 3-e it's still off by an order of magnitude of what he wants.  More to the point when I use DFS only in coregen the only option I have is clkfx (clkdv isn't even available so the previous analysis doesn't even hold).  The minimum output frequency according to coregen is 5 MHz for a spartan 3a-dsp.  Is there a way to get to 1 kHz output from a DCM on a spartan 3 device?

Comment: I am not sure we are looking at the same document here. If you go to page 67 of the above document, under DFS, you will see for "Extended Spartan-3A Family FPGAs" the frequency range is specified as "0.2 to 333 MHz"

Comment: I see that, but what I'm saying is that when you use DFS mode it appears as though the minimum *output* frequency is still limited.  CLKDV doesn't appear to be enabled -- the only outputs I can use are CLKFX and CLKFX180. The min CLKFX *output* is much higher than 1 kHz (5 Mhz minimum from what I see).  At least from what I see (and what coregen lets me do -- on spartan 3a-dsp).  So for the extended spartan 3a you can put 200 kHz in, but I don't think you can get anything less than that out -- I think you're capped by clkfx output limitations.

Comment: Which is why I think you just need some enable logic on a higher frequency clock.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what clock frequency you have available. If you have a 20MHz clock source, you need to divided it by 20000 in order to get 1KHz, you can do it in VHDL or use a DCM to do this.

This is from an example on how to create a 1kHz clock from a 20MHz input:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity clk20Hz is
    Port (
        clk_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
        reset  : in  STD_LOGIC;
        clk_out: out STD_LOGIC
    );
end clk200Hz;

architecture Behavioral of clk20Hz is
    signal temporal: STD_LOGIC;
    signal counter : integer range 0 to 10000 := 0;
begin
    frequency_divider: process (reset, clk_in) begin
        if (reset = '1') then
            temporal <= '0';
            counter <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
            if (counter = 10000) then
                temporal <= NOT(temporal);
                counter <= 0;
            else
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    clk_out <= temporal;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Are you sure this divides the clock by 20000?

Comment: Well it toggles the clock every 10k cycle which gives a full cycle every 20k pulse

Comment: True it should be <10000 :)